# Code repeating although not in a repeating loop python

Tags: file, python-3.x

Only been learning python for a couple of weeks so ignore any ugly pieces of code.

```
pass1 = "AJ00JJJ"
userfile = open("DATABASE.txt","r")

password = input("ENTER_MAIN:FRAME_PASSWORD: ")

if password == str(pass1):

username = input("INPUT_USERNAME: ")
for line in userfile:
    if username == line:
        print("WELCOME")
        userfile.close()
    elif username != line: 
        print("USER_UNKNOWN.. ADDING_TO_DATABASE")
        userfile_write = open("DATABASE.txt","a")
        nextLine="%s\n" % (username)
        userfile_write.write(nextLine)
        userfile_write.close()
```

so what I'm making is a program where you put in the password, then put in a username, if the username isn't already in the file, then add the inputted username onto a new line and save.

this works, but it keeps on adding the username and printing 'USER_UNKNOWN.. ADDING_TO_DATABASE'

any reason why?

Comment: Note that `line` will include `'\n'` - have you tried `if username == line.strip()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote the loop to go through each line of the file; unless you stop the loop, it will continue to do so.

I think you want to wait until *after* the loops is done (and the name was not found) before adding it to the file.